# ARM template deploying an azureKeyVault and retrieving an objectId using an inline Powershell script. Not happening for me

Tags: powershell, azure-resource-manager, inline-scripting

I'm thinking this is the best place to post this as you guys are the cream of the crop. I'm very new to azure Devops and I am playing around ARM templates and have created a relatively simple azurekeyvault. In my code I am trying to create an inline PowerShell script that will grab someone deploying the ARM templates ObjectId and storing it into the parameter, as opposed to entering it in manually or having to deploy it from the azure portal. I just cannot seem to get it to work, and it is quite frustrating. I was wondering if someone could take a quick look and maybe explain what I am doing wrong. Very Kind regards.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "vaults_azurekeyvault_vault_name": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "tenantId": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "objectId": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            
            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
            "apiVersion": "2022-07-01",
            "name": "[parameters('vaults_azurekeyvault_vault_name')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "sku": {
                    "family": "A",
                    "name": "Standard"
                },
                "tenantId": "[parameters('tenantId')]",
                "networkAcls": {
                    "bypass": "AzureServices",
                    "defaultAction": "Deny",
                    "ipRules": [],
                    "virtualNetworkRules": []
                },
                "accessPolicies": [
                    {
                        "tenantId": "[parameters('tenantId')]",
                        "objectId": "[parameters('objectId')]",
                        //"objectId": "[if(equals(parameters('objectId'), ''), reference('getUserObjectId').outputs.result.value, parameters('objectId'))]",
                        "permissions": {
                            "keys": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Update",
                                "Create"
                            ],
                            "secrets": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Set"
                            ],
                            "certificates": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Update",
                                "Create"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "enabledForDeployment": true,
                "enabledForDiskEncryption": true,
                "enabledForTemplateDeployment": true,
                "enableSoftDelete": false,
                //"softDeleteRetentionInDays": 7,
                "enableRbacAuthorization": false,
                "vaultUri": "[concat('https://', parameters('vaults_azurekeyvault_vault_name'), '.vault.azure.net/')]",
                "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
            "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
            "name": "getUserObjectId",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "kind": "AzurePowerShell",
            "properties": {
                "azPowerShellVersion": "3.0",
                "arguments": "",
                "scriptContent": "Get-AzContext | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Account | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id",
                "cleanupPreference": "OnSuccess",
                "timeout": "PT1H",
                "retentionInterval": "P1D"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys",
            "apiVersion": "2022-07-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('vaults_azurekeyvault_vault_name'), '/azurekeyvault-certificate')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('vaults_azurekeyvault_vault_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "attributes": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "nbf": 1676439340,
                    "exp": 1707975940
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys",
            "apiVersion": "2022-07-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('vaults_azurekeyvault_vault_name'), '/azurevault')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('vaults_azurekeyvault_vault_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "attributes": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "exportable": false
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
            "apiVersion": "2022-07-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('vaults_azurekeyvault_vault_name'), '/azurekeyvault-certificate')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('vaults_azurekeyvault_vault_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "contentType": "application/x-pkcs12"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
            "apiVersion": "2022-07-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('vaults_azurekeyvault_vault_name'), '/azurekeyvault-secret')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('vaults_azurekeyvault_vault_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "contentType": "text/plain"
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "objectId": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[reference('getUserObjectId').outputs.result.value]"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the errors you are getting?

Comment: I honestly think I am doing something wrong in the Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts that I'm deploying. I try and deploy into my azure portal using powershell and the inline script just doesn't want to work. I'm very green so I'm not entirely sure how to troubleshoot

Comment: I don’t think this will fix anything but ```Get-AzContext | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Account | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id``` can be simplified to ```(Get-AzContext).Account.Id```

Comment: Do yourself a huge favor and use Bicep instead of trying to mess around in ARM JSON directly.

Comment: I know mate, but I have to for a work project unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

ah okay, forgot one obvious thing you are doing wrong:

```
$output = (Get-AzContext).Account.Id
Write-Output $output
$DeploymentScriptOutputs = @{}
$DeploymentScriptOutputs['accountId'] = $output
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template#sample-templates

also, check you've grant all the needed permissions to run deploymentScripts

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time to have a look and help, cheers for the link as well. ill try it now